# reconfigure audio jack connector

Tags: soundcard, audio-jack

my sound card (Realtek AUDIO) has the main audio output jack connector broken... (The green one)

I noticed that windows can reconfigure the audio Line-in (The blue one) as audio output for headphones. Now I can hear audio again.

Is it possibile to do the same in ubuntu / linux ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `alsa-tools-gui` and then run `hdajackretask`. You can override there any pin you need. Normally the change will be valid until next reboot. If you want to make it permanent press `Install boot override`.